How to grep in commits from specific author(s) with git?
How to grep in commits of specific author(s) with git (i.e., w/o piping to grep)?
I could use git log and pipe into grep, but maybe there's a better (faster?) way?
git log --author="John Doe <jdoe@host>" -p | grep "some interesting stuff"


You don’t use git-grep(1) on the log.  You use git log --grep=<something> --author=<something>

If you mean grep through the diff: git log ... -S for fixed strings and git log ... -G for a regex.

thanks! I realize I had a false premise here, and re-phrased the question to not ask specifically about git-grep. What you suggest is exactly what I want, thanks!

As a @Guildenstern says, you don't need to use git grep, you just need to add --grep flag to your git log command, like this:
git log --author=<something> --grep=<something> 

This grep flag will search only within commit messages. If you need to search in the diff (e.g., some string that was added or removed in the change) you can use the -S flag, like this:
git log --author=<something> -S'changes'

And if you need to search by regex you can use -G flag, like this:
git log --author=<something> -G'^changes'

This will find any changes in the diff that contain a line starting with changes.
For more information about the differences between the -S and -G flags you can check here (thanks @j6t):
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt--Gltregexgt
A few more interesting examples
Find commits from multiple authors
git log --author=<something> --author=<someone>

Use multiple grep flag:
git log --author=<something> --grep=fix --grep=feat

If you need to find a commit that contains both words in a single commit message, add the --all-match flag, like this:
git log --author=<something> --grep=fix --grep=feat --all-match


The difference between -S and -G is much more fundamental than just fixed string vs. regular expression.

super, thank you! updated the answer.
